# Append element to column with numpy.ndarray datatype in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I want to append a string to a column which is a numpy.ndarray object.The following code is not working:

```
def filter_by_player(df, players, team):
    filtered_df = df[df['player'].isin(players)]
    filtered_df['league'] = filtered_df['league'].apply(lambda x: x + [team])
    return filtered_df
```

the league column looks like this ['barca','real','sevilla']. I want to add to it but the code above is not working.

players = ['messi', 'benzema', 'busquets']

```
league_df
player      | team
messi       | ['barca']
lewandowski | ['dortmund', 'bayern', 'barca']
```

when i call the function filter_by_player(players, 'psg')

the new dataframe league_df should become this as messi is in the list of players:

```
player      | team
messi       | ['barca', 'psg']
```

Comment: What do you want to be in the `league` column after filtering?

Comment: Can you provide some sample data and the desired output for that sample data?

Comment: Hi, i added more information

Comment: so you want to append the `psg` to the list of players tohat you pass as parameter? and then filter the data by that list as well? Its unclear if you are performing 2 tasks (addition of team name and filtering ) or you are just filtering.

Comment: the filtering is straight forward. it is the  appending I am having issues with. league column is an numpy.ndarray object and so appending is not straight forward

Comment: whats the error you are facing? your code seems fine

Comment: no error. it just doesn't append. i am pretty sure it is because it is an numpy.ndarray object.

Comment: can you do this - `type(league_df.iloc[0,1])` and post the output

Comment: `player              object
team         object`
output

Comment: no something is not right, because when run on the sample data you have posted this has different results. Basically what i want you to print is the type of each element in the league column.check the second section of my answer.

Comment: I was able to figure it out. I converted the numpy.ndarray object to a list and I simply appended. Thanks for your time

Comment: sure, do check the answer below as that should solve your initially posted answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, each of the elements in the `team` or `league` column is a numpy array. So, use `np.append` instead of appending lists. Try this -

```
import numpy as np

def filter_by_player(df, players, team):
    filtered_df = df[df['player'].isin(players)]
    filtered_df['team'] = filtered_df['team'].apply(np.append, args=([team]))
    return filtered_df

new_df = filter_by_player(league_df, ['messi'], 'psg')
print(new_df)
```

```
  player          team
0  messi  [barca, psg]
```

---

Just to double check if the initial datatype and post datatypes are numpy -

```
print(type(league_df.iloc[0,1]))
print(type(new_df.iloc[0,1]))
```

```
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

---

**EDIT:** If you arent not strict about keeping it as a numpy array, try this -

```
def filter_by_player(df, players, team):
    filtered_df = df[df['player'].isin(players)]
    filtered_df['league'] = filtered_df['league'].apply(lambda x: list(x)+[team])
    return filtered_df

new_df = filter_by_player(league_df, ['messi'], 'psg')
print(new_df)
print(type(league_df.iloc[0,1]))
print(type(new_df.iloc[0,1]))
```

```
  player        league
0  messi  [barca, psg]

<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
<class 'list'>
```

Comment: This works! More elegant than mine! Thank you!!

Comment: have also added the list approach (modified your approach), since you mentioned you are not too strict about keeping it as numpy. Glad to help!